# Send email with out html tags

Tags: php

I am trying to send a mail, that mail body is generate from a text editor, am using mailto function, but mail contain html tags, i don't want to show the html tags. Please help me... my code is like that, echo "";

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. Send a plaintext email or send a properly constructed HTML email?

Comment: I want to send full constructed text, it may be with color, with paragraph, bold text and all that, but it will not show the html tags.

Comment: Take a look at @Shankar's answer bellow then, should be what you are looking for. Also, please add the clarification to the original question, it is ambiguous this way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the content type as **`text/html`** on your headers to send a fully HTML-Enabled Email.

Do like this

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

You can find the full code from the PHP Manual [`here`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$message = "your html message here";

$message = strip_tags($message);
```

this will remove all html tags..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate HTML content in the email body you need to use a proper client as well, gmail for example is not able to render HTML if you paste it on the email. Use Thunderbird for example, you can insert HTML on the email when writing it.